Stripe Embedded Form functionality in Salesforce LWC
We have developed an app that basically helps in accepting payments from Stripe.
We have used Embedded Form in it where we have to pass this stripe's js cdn to use Stripe method pass public key & client secret and embedded form will appear.
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

So the issue here I didn't find a way to directly use this inside lwc so I have an lwc within it I open the VF page and within the vf page, I am embedding JS using this way which is working fine.
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
document.body.appendChild(script);

But it is giving me an issue in Source Scanner to not embed js dynamically.
Is there any better way to use Stripe Embedded Form functionality in lwc?
Stripe Embedded form
https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/embedded/quickstart?lang=java

